# Passing an array from python to shared DLL, seeing access violation error

Tags: python, ctypes

The C function from DLL:

```
Multi(double Freq, double Power, int ports[], int Size)
Need to pass the 3rd parameter as an array from python
```

Tried the following different codes:

A:

```
import ctypes
pyarr = [2,3]
arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(pyarr))(*pyarr)

lp = CDLL(CDLL_file)
lp.Multi(c_double(Freq), c_double(Power), arr ,c_int(Size))`
```

This code shows an error 
       ## exception :: access violation reading 0x00000000000

B:

```
retarr = (ctypes.c_int*2)()
retarr[0] =2
retarr[1] =3

lp = CDLL(CDLL_file)
lp.Multi(c_double(Freq), c_double(Power), retarr ,c_int(Size))`
```

This code shows an error

```
## exception :: access violation reading 0x00000000000
```

C: The same code using ctypes.byref also tried ......

My understanding is the function expects an array as argument ,
Tries passing an array as such as well address.
Both cases , it didn't work
Do anyone sees any mistake in my understanding or any other to work this out ??

Comment: What is `Size` set to?

Answer (score 1):

Specify your `argtypes`.  Given this test.dll source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void Multi(double Freq, double Power, int ports[], int Size)
{
    int i;
    printf("%f %f\n",Freq,Power);
    for(i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        printf("%d\n",ports[i]);
}
```

This works:

```
from ctypes import *
dll = CDLL('test')
Multi = dll.Multi
Multi.argtypes = (c_double,c_double,POINTER(c_int),c_int)
Multi.restype = None

ports = (c_int * 2)(100,200)
Multi(1.1,2.2,ports,len(ports))
```

Output:

```
1.100000 2.200000
100
200
```